# how to find a string in a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do i find a string or a list in a text file. If i have a text file filled with words only, random words, not sentences, how do i find a string inside it. lets say I take a user input, how do I test or check if the string input by the user exist in the text file.

so far i have this:

```
x = open('sample.txt')

for a in x:
    b = a.split()        #converts the string from the txt to a list

c = input('enter: ')        #user input

if any(c in a for a in b):
    print('yes')
```

want to make a simple spellchecker. so from the user input string i want to check if that string matches the strings/list in the txt file

Answer (score 5):

You mean, how to find a word in this file? That's

```
with open("sample.txt") as input:
    dictionary = set(input.read().split())
```

then

```
w in dictionary
```

for your word `w`.

Comment: can you explain what you did in the second line.

`dictionary = set(input.read().split())`

Comment: @SabbibChowDhury: `input.read()` reads the entire file's contents. `.split()` then tokenizes the contents and `set()` constructs a set (removing duplicates and allowing fast lookup) from the list of tokens.

Answer (score 3):

You asked three related but different questions:

*1. "how do i find a string or a list in a text file."*

```
text = input('enter: ')
data = open("sample.txt").read()
position = data.find(text)
if position != -1:
    print("Found at position", position)
else:
    print("Not found")
```

*2. "how do I test or check if the string input by the user exist in the text file"*

```
text = input('enter: ')
data = open("sample.txt").read()
if text in data:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

*3. "I want to make a simple spellchecker. so from the user input string i want to check if that string matches the strings/list in the txt file"*

Make a dictionary like this, globally in a module:

```
dictionary = open("sample.txt").read().split()
```

Then you use the dictionary by importing it:

```
from themodule import dictionary
```

And you check if a word is in the dictionary like so:

```
'word' in dictionary
```

Comment: @SabbibChowDhury: Substitute it with the name of the module where you put the dictionary.